pythonocc - pyqt5 backend could not be loaded
pyqt5 backend could not be loaded.
from OCC.Display.backend import load_backend
load_backend("pyqt5")

I used "pip install PyQt5" and the requirement already satisfied in visual studio community developer command prompt.
Please help.
